After installing streamlit in Pycharm , not recognized and getting error as streamlit not recognized
streamlit : The term 'streamlit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ streamlit run Home.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (streamlit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

